# Is it possible for a Perl script running on a Unix/Linux platform to create Windows Shortcuts?

Tags: windows, linux, perl, unix, shortcut

If I want to create a *nix symlink, I'll call `symlink();`, if i'm running a script on windows and I want to create a shortcut, I'd use `Win32::Shortcut`.

But what if I want to create a Windows shortcut if running a script from a *nix machine?

I'm accessing a SMB share on a Windows Server 2003 machine from my *nix machine.

Comment: Depends on however you are accessing the Windows from your *nix machine.

Comment: I'm accessing a SMB share on a Windows Server 2003 machine from my *nix machine. (Added it to the question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I don't know if Samba provides an API for that. On the other hand, Windows shortcuts are just `.lnk` files in a specific format.

Comment: So I should be able to write a function that could generate this specific file type? Are there any tutorials available regarding writing binary files?

Comment: @Powertieke: In theory, yes you should be able to write a function to create such a file.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since the initial question, but I've had the same issue and found a solution.

I wrote an application whose goal is to allow anyone to create lnk files from any OS.
I started writting it in bash and then I converted it in C (the sources are available).

It's still fresh, so except me nobody tested yet, but you can have a look here :
  http://www.mamachine.org/mslink/index.en.html